# nginx as a reverse proxy looses cookies

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, cookies, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup an nginx as a reverse proxy for my web app.
The scheme:

1. nginx on a server host receives requests and transfers them to another host
2. nginx works as a HTTPS (wildcard certificate used globally), web app as a HTTP
3. at this stage i don't need nginx caching (at least while trying to figure out how to make it work)
4. nginx redirects all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
5. nginx blocks hostless requests

Here is a config:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    ssl_certificate             ./certs/my_domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key         ./certs/my_domain.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    ssl_session_cache           shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout         10m;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

    server {
        listen  80;
        return  444;
    }

    server {
        listen      80;
        server_name my_domain.com www.my_domain.com *.my_domain.com;
        return      301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen      443 ssl;
        server_name my_domain.com;

        location / {
            root    html;
            index   index.html index.htm;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen      443 ssl;
        server_name expert.my_domain.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass          http://192.168.0.83:50000;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header    Host $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

While viewing nginx docs i've noticed that caching has to be turned on explicitly (proxy_cache off by default). But i'm not sure if there is something else has to be done to turn it off completely.

The sequence:

1. log in to the web app through nginx
2. authorize and get a cookie
3. open a second tab with the app
4. get a cookie from step (2)
5. refresh the page
6. loose a cookie (??)

Here is the results after step (3):

```
Request Method: GET
Request Scheme: https
Request Path: /
Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ky;q=0.6
Cookie: .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=*** LONG ASP NET CORE IDENTITY COOKIE ***
Host: expert.my_domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
X-Original-Proto: http
X-Real-IP: 192.168.0.83
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
X-Original-For: [::ffff:192.168.0.12]:54035
```

The cookie and stuff is there.
And here is how it looks like after simple refresh:

```
Request Method: GET
Request Scheme: https
Request Path: /
Request Headers:
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ky;q=0.6
Host: expert.my_domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
X-Original-Proto: http
X-Real-IP: 192.168.0.83
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
X-Original-For: [::ffff:192.168.0.12]:54038
```

Notice the absence of cookie part.

I believe this has something to do with caching. Seems that after opening the page in another tab, browser (chrome in this case) shows me a cached version where cookie is present. Not sure who caches it though - nginx or chrome. And after that whoosh and it's gone.

Why i think this is an issue with nginx? When doing the same thing with the app directly there are no problems of any kind. It fully works as expected.

What could be missing here? Is caching problem involved? How to completely disable caching with nginx?

Comment: Check what’s going on with your browser dev tools. Cookies are sent by the client, and it’s the client’s responsibility to store them and send them with every request. So you should check in your client (the browser) what happens to the cookie values. Especially check the `Set-Cookie` response header to see if the cookie is maybe set for a different domain or path.

Comment: Thanks. It appeared to be cross site requests (which are forbidden in the app itself) that were made by one of my extensions - speed dial. Don't know why i didn't see that before using nginx. Will be contacting author.